How to Encrypt and Decrypt Files in the App Storage
To secure app storage, I encrypted the storage using EncryptedStorage as explained here. That is,
EncryptedStorage.install("your-pass-encryption-key")

I created a text file to be shared and opened/used by the same app in another device.
The problem is that this file can't be open/used in another device. It says that this file is encrypted.
How can I decrypt it to be able to open or use it in the same app in another device?
EDIT
I did the following to create the file to share as a .txt file so as to be able to share it using plain/text mime type.
String databasePath = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("TestDB.db");
String mimeType = "application/vnd.sqlite3";
mimeType = "application/x-sqlite3";
mimeType = "plain/text";

try {
    FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    InputStream is = fss.openInputStream(databasePath);

    //Copy from FSS to Storage
    Util.copy(is, Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("TestDB.txt"));
    String fileToSharePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "TestDB.txt";
    Log.p("FileToSharePath " + fileToSharePath);
    Display.getInstance().share(fileToSharePath, null, mimeType);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.p("Share error: " + e);
}

I did the following to browse the shared file using FileChooser in another device and save it as .db file in the app database directory.
FileChooser.showOpenDialog("txt", ev -> {

    if (ev == null) {
        Log.p("no file selected");
    } else {
        String filePath = (String) ev.getSource();
        Log.p("FilePath " + filePath);
        try {
            FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
            InputStream is = fss.openInputStream(filePath);

            String databasePath = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("TestDB.db");
            OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(databasePath);
            Util.copy(is, os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.p("Create DB error: " + e);
        }
    }
});


You need to include code. Files are encrypted when written via the Storage API and decrypted when read via the Storage API. I'm guessing you tried to read them via the FileSystemStorage API.

I have added code snippets of how I am doing it

The following creates a encrypted SampleText.txt to app storage which can't be read when open in text editor. It can only be read by the app.
   EncryptedStorage.install("your-pass-encryption-key")
                
   private void writeAndReadCipherFile() {
    try {    
        //write encrypted file to the app storage
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("SampleText.txt"))) {
            w.write("Hey there big brother");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }

        //read encrypted file from the app storage
        InputStream is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("SampleText.txt");
        int nextChar = is.read();
      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (nextChar > -1) {
            sb.append((char) nextChar);
            nextChar = is.read();
        }
        
        Log.p("FileContent " + sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.p("Error " + e);
    }
}

The following reads and encrypt database file content using BouncyCastle and save encrypted database file in the app home path directory home/.cn1
It also read encrypted file content, decrypts and save the decrypted file in home/.cn1.
ISO-8859-1 encoding is required in OutputStreamWriter to ensure all characters in the file bytes are read as expected.
Windows-1252 encoding also tries but some hexadecimal are read as ?.
private void encryptDatabaseFile() {
    try {
        String filePath = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("TestDB.db");
        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        InputStream is = fss.openInputStream(filePath);
        byte[] plainBytes = Util.readInputStream(is);

        //encrypt database file content
        byte[] cipherByteArray = FilesCipher.encryptFile(plainBytes);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cipherByteArray);

        String encryptedFilePath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "EncryptedDB.db";
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(encryptedFilePath), "ISO-8859-1")) {//ISO-8859-1 Windows-1252 UTF-8 
            int nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            while (nextChar > -1) {
                char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                w.write(charArray);
                nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }

        //decrypt database file content
        InputStream decryptInputStream = fss.openInputStream(encryptedFilePath);
        byte[] cipherBytes = Util.readInputStream(decryptInputStream);
        byte[] plainByteArray = FilesCipher.decryptFile(cipherBytes);
        ByteArrayInputStream decryptedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(plainByteArray);

        String decryptedFilePath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "DecryptedDB.db";
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(decryptedFilePath), "ISO-8859-1")) {//ISO-8859-1 Windows-1252 UTF-8 
            int nextChar = decryptedInputStream.read();
            while (nextChar > -1) {
                char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                w.write(charArray);
                nextChar = decryptedInputStream.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.p("Error " + e);
    }
}

The following FilesCipher class handles encryption and decryption
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class FilesCipher {

    private static PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher;
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "Your 16 Character Secret Key";
    private static final String I_VECTOR = "Your 16 Character initialization vector";

    public static byte[] encryptFile(byte[] plainBytes) {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));

            byte sKey[] = SECRET_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] iv = I_VECTOR.getBytes("UTF-8");

            KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(sKey);

            CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv);
            cipher.init(true, ivAndKey);
            byte[] cipherBytes = cipherData(plainBytes);
            byteArray = Base64.encode(cipherBytes);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalArgumentException
                | CryptoException e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }

    public static byte[] decryptFile(byte[] cipherBytes) {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));

            byte sKey[] = SECRET_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] iv = I_VECTOR.getBytes("UTF-8");

            KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(sKey);

            byte[] cipherData = Base64.decode(cipherBytes);
            CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv);

            cipher.init(false, ivAndKey);

            byteArray = cipherData(cipherData);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalArgumentException
                | CryptoException e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }

    private static byte[] cipherData(byte[] data) throws CryptoException {
        int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
        byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
        int len1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
        int len2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, len1);
        int actualLen = len1 + len2;
        byte[] result = new byte[actualLen];
        System.arraycopy(outBuf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
        return result;
    }
}

This also makes it possible to keep the database encrypted. That is, after database is created, this database file can be encrypted using FilesCipher.encryptFile() then save this as the database.
Before executing Create, Read, Update & Delete queries, decrypt the database file using FilesCipher.decryptFile().
After executing queries, encrypt the database again using FilesCipher.encryptFile()

How can database file be encrypted ?

You would need to create a custom native build of sqlite and ship it with your application. Sqlite needs to be compiled with encryption enabled for this to work. This isn't hard but it's a pain since you need to package native executable code for all platforms.  Steve did something like this for spatial support in sqlite, the process is similar.

This sounds sophisticated, Instead I decided to encrypt database file content as in my edits in this answer.

You're using Storage instead of FileSystemStorage in this line:
Util.copy(is, Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("TestDB.txt"));

This encrypts the file, notice that this won't work on the devices consistently anyway... But then you use FileSystemStorage again to read the data (which is encrypted).
String fileToSharePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "TestDB.txt";

The solution is to use FileSystemStorage for everything you want to share. Encrypting the database file in this way won't work anyway.

How can I encrypt this SQLite database?

Do you want to encrypt the database while working with it or to encrypt a database file before sharing it. Those are VERY different things.

I would like to encrypt the database when working with it. Since it will be shared directly without any modification, I guess it will still be encrypted when it is being shared.

That might not be the right assumption since an encryption might be device specific and the resulting file might not work. It's also a MUCH harder process. To do that you will need to build native versions of sqlite and package your own versions with the application as explained here.

From this blog The cn1lib extends the Database class & allows you to plug-in a custom version of sqlite to replace the Database . This sounds a bit of a challenge since there is no demo for it.

How about encrypting the database file before sharing it? How can it be encrypted before sharing?

It's a huge challenge. There is an OSS sample but it's technically challenging which is why I didn't recommend it. Encrypting the DB just means using the encryption API before saving the file and the decryption API before copying it into place. E.g you can look at our encrypted storage and understand how to encrypt/decrypt a file.
